# syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end in my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please i need help validating this code.
Using Ruby 2.3.3 & Rails 5.2
i think all ending anchors are given though

```
<% if current_user.id != user.id %>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="pane-body">
        <center>
            <% if !current_user.following?(user) %>
            <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build) do |f| %>
            <div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, user.id %></div>
            <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <% end %>
        <% else %>
             <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: user.id),
              html: {method: :delete}) do |f| %>
              <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-default" %>
             <% end %>
        </center>

    </div>

</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
  <% else %>
    <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: user.id), html: {method: :delete}) do |f| %>
      <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-default" %>
    <% end %>
</center>
```

You have the `end` to close the block for `form_for` but not for ending the `if-else`

```
  <% else %>
    <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: user.id), html: {method: :delete}) do |f| %>
      <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-default" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</center>
```

Answer (score 2):

Properly indenting helps a lot:

```
<% if current_user.id != user.id %>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="pane-body">
      <center>
        <% if !current_user.following?(user) %>
          <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build) do |f| %>
            <div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, user.id %></div>
            <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          <% end %>
        <% else %>
          <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: user.id), html: {method: :delete}) do |f| %>
            <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-default" %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Your end on line 13 closed off the `form_for do |f|` block, meaning you needed one more to close off the `if \ else do` block